# How to disable the label when switch is off and switch is on enable in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi when the switch is off then the lable should be gray color like lable should disable , if on then lable should enable Using angular

Here fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dgj7s5sk/8/

```
 <label>check1</label>
  <div class="onoffswitch">
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" 
  checked="checked" />
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"> <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

</label>
</div>
  <label>check2</label>
  <div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2"  />
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2"> <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

</label>
</div>
```

Please me in this issue. Thanks

Comment: why to disable Label. Label not takes any input. Use css to addClass and removeclass on label.

Comment: yeah not like disable i need to change color of label to grey if it is off.

Comment: You could use ng-class

Comment: Create a class for disabled label.
Use ng-class to apply this class based on checkbox value.

Comment: Ya.. That is what I mean. use addClass and removeClass for this.

Comment: I have not worked on angular so some one help me out in this i know in jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the updated [fiddle with solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/dd6L0so2/1/)

In your example, you were not declaring your code as an angular app.

What I did:

1. Used Angular framework(See 1st dropsown on left under 'Frameworks & Extensions')
2. Declared as angular app. See `<div ng-app>` on 1st line.
3. Defined `ng-model` for both inputs `switches.switch1` and `switches.switch2`.
4. Defined a new class for disabled label

`.disabled-class {
    color:gray;
}`

5. Applied conditional class using ng-class

`<label ng-class="(switches.switch1)?'':'disabled-class'">check1</label>`

`<label ng-class="(switches.switch2)?'':'disabled-class'">check2</label>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer its helped me :)